# How to return a string value instead of Json from a mongodb aggregate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have created a function to return value of  'minHospitalization' field from db.Response from the below function is '[{"minHospitalization":1}]'

I would like to return the value as '1' instead of returning value in json format.How do i achieve it?

```
var getHospitalStayDuration = function (req, res, callback) {

    var treatmentName = req.query.procedurename

    treatmentDescModel.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "isDisable": "N", "treatmentName": treatmentName } },
        { "$project": { "_id": 0, "minHospitalization": 1} }

    ], function (err, result) {

        if (err) {
           //do smthing
        } else if (!result.length) {
            //do something
        }
        else {
             //result= [{"minHospitalization":1}]   

          //callback(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)).minHospitalization);
            callback(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))
            //How to return 1 instead of result??

            }
    })

}
```

Comment: What about `callback( result[0].minHospitalization )` ... :/.

Comment: I tried printing console.log("minHospitalization - " + result.minHospitalization) and the output is 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `key` :

```
callback(result[0].minHospitalization)
```

Comment: Thanks.This is exactly what i was looking for